# I have question about RSS feed

Tags: rss

I am stuck on this. My project is to do this..This week you will be creating a theme for a web development company.

```
* You can use http://www.1kbgrid.com/ for a base design.
* Come up with a color scheme that will match this logo.
* Decide what your top links should be.  Create an RSS feed for these top pages.
* Create a report that states the scope of the project (why you are doing it), the top level pages, why you picked the color scheme,etc.
```

ok I have done and rss thing and this is what it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Web design software</title>
    <link></link>
    <description>Has different soft ware and prices.</description>
    <item>
      <title>Adobe Dreamweaver</title>
      <link>http://shopping.yahoo.com/search?p=web%20design</link>
      <description>This tells you how much it cost and what it is
      for.</description>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Frontpage 2003 upgrade</title>
      <link>
      http://www.softwaremedia.com/microsoft/frontpage/frontpage-
      2003-upgrade.html?ovchn=PGR&amp;ovcrn=39202323&amp;ovtac=CMP&amp;ovcpn=frontpage-2003---upgrade</link>
      <description>THis is to help build a better web
      site.</description>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>WebPlus X4 Website Maker Mini Box</title>
      <link>
      http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?sku=A3310055&amp;cs=04&amp;c=us&amp;l=en&amp;dgc=SS&amp;cid=52102&amp;lid=1342490</link>
      <description>It helps you to make websites</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

what i am stuck on is how to decide what my top link should be.Create an RSS feed for those top pages. Ok the question is am I suppose to link the rss feed or if that is even possible. I am totally lost on this question. Thank you for ready this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You generally link to RSS documents from your main site by using the `<link>` tag. It should look something like this

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Top Web design software Feed" href="http://LINKTOMYRSSFILE" />
```

If you site is a dynamic site, you'll need to replace LINKTOMYRSSFILE with the link to the file that generates your RSS. If it's a static file, just save this file in your server and point it to that.

Also, your main channel link should point to the link of the page that displays all this content.

**EDIT**

First off, you should use the W3C service to validate your feed. They point out what's wrong/best practices and tells you how you can fix them (use the help link next to the error)

Make sure the empty `<link></link>` tag contains a url to your site

To answer your questions in the comments

> **Missing atom:link with rel="self"**
>
> According to the RSS Advisory Board's
>   Best Practices Profile, identifying a
>   feed's URL within the feed makes it
>   more portable, self-contained, and
>   easier to cache. For these reasons, a
>   feed should contain an atom:link used
>   for this purpose.

via : http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html

You can fix this by changing your `<rss>` tag to

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

And having the following above items

```
<atom:link href="http://LINKTOFEED" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
```

> **Line 12, column 2: item should contain a guid element**
>
> It's recommended that you provide the
>   guid, and if possible make it a
>   permalink. This enables aggregators to
>   not repeat items, even if there have
>   been editing changes.
>
> A frequently asked question about
>   s is how do they compare to
>   s. Aren't they the same thing?
>   Yes, in some content systems, and no
>   in others. In some systems,  is
>   a permalink to a weblog item. However,
>   in other systems, each  is a
>   synopsis of a longer article, 
>   points to the article, and  is
>   the permalink to the weblog entry.

So in your case adding the following to each of your items will fix it

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">LINKTOSOFTWARE</guid>
```

Replace LINKTOSOFTWARE with the links in your `<link></link>` tags.

I corrected your mistakes and your feed validates fine. You just need to fix these errors.

You can follow this tutorial on how to add RSS feeds to your pages : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/RSS/Getting_Started/Syndicating

It's as simple as adding an HTML tag into your page.

Comment: I still do not understand does anyone have a web site or anything maybe i can read....

Comment: what part don't you understand? I can help you if you're a bit more specific.

Comment: Yes I went and vaildated my rss file its comming back with this Missing atom:link with rel="self" and line 12, column 2: item should contain a guid element. I am still pretty confused on the part she is asking decide what your top links should be. Create and RSS feed for these top pages.I did post what my RSS file look like not the pages are those consider the web pages i put in my rss file. I also dont understand how to connect the rss file to my webpage so It is there.